# Task bar changes transparency on mouse-over

Tags: windows, display, taskbar

Windows 10 taskbar (on the main screen only) is out of focus and unclear when not hovering the mouse over it. I can’t find any settings for this annoying issue. The taskbar is not hiding, but unclear.
I've been looking through ease of access and all personalization and taskbar settings. Anyone has an idea on how to fix this?

Not hovering:
[image]

Hovering:
[image]

Comment: It's not 'out of focus' it's changing transparency. Title updated to reflect this.

Comment: [How to turn off transparency in Windows 10 | My Computer My Way](https://mcmw.abilitynet.org.uk/how-turn-transparency-windows-10#:~:text=Alternatively%2C%20select%20the%20Start%20Menu,to%20turn%20off%20transparent%20effects.)

Comment: @ Tetsuji, You are correct, thanks.

Comment: @ DavidPostill, Thanks but makes no difference to the problem.

Comment: Login in with a new user account somehow fixed the problem. Original user account is also without issues now. So problem solved  :-)